# Creating Subfolder inside a folder using PhotoKit

Tags: ios, iphone, photokit, phphotolibrary

I understand how one can create a folder programmatically using Apple's PhotoKit API and add Photos to the folder.

```
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        let req = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: "FolderName")

    }, completionHandler: { success, error in
        if !success { print("Error creating album: \(String(describing: error)).") }
    })
```

Is there a way to create subfolders inside this folder using PhotoKit?

Comment: You can try this one: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phcollectionlistchangerequest/1622851-addchildcollections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present Apple is exposed api for create single album. 
Even manually you can't create a folder inside another folder from the device.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phcollectionlistchangerequest

Call the `creationRequestForCollectionList(withTitle:)` method to create a new asset collection.

Call the `deleteCollectionLists(_:)` method to delete existing asset collections.

Call the `init(for:) or init(for:childCollections:)` method to modify a collection’s metadata or its list of child collections.